# Relationship between complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

If f is an analytic function on C 
And if $$|f(1/n)|\le(1/n^{3/2})$$ for each n belong Naturals how to show $${n^2f(1/n)}$$ is bounded

Comment: Do you mean that the sequence $(n^2f(1/n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded? The number $n^2f(1/n)$ for $n$ fixed is of course bounded as $f$ is defined on the entire complex plane.

Comment: Yes the sequence

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Clearly $f(0)=0.$ What does $f'(0)$ equal, and what does that say about the power series of $f$ at $0?$

Comment: I can see that f(0) due to the limit at infinity but how to deduce any thing about the derivative

Comment: What is the definition of $f'(0)$?